# Optimization of multiple inputs model in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am working with medical data and trying to build a TF model with 2 inputs.
-The first input is a numpy array containing data about several Patient. Some tests are made on each Patient regularly (e.g check the weigth of the Patient). They will appear several times in my array.
-The second one is an image of the Patient lungs.

Suppose I have 2 patients named Bob and Jean. Bob has been tested 3 times and Jean has been tested 2 times. I will have 3 rows in the array for Bob and 2 rows for Jean. But for each patient, I have only one picture. So in my DataGenerator, I will have to use this picture 3 times, for each row.
My first input would look like this:

```
['Name', 'Age', 'Weight']  
['Bob', 54, 80]  
['Bob', 55, 81]  
['Bob', 52, 79]  
['Jean', 40, 90]   
['Jean', 41, 88]
```

And the second one like this:

```
Bob_img = 'Array representing the image of Bob lungs' 
Jean_img = 'Array representing the image of Jean lungs' 

[Picture_array]
[Bob_img]
[Bob_img]
[Bob_img]
[Jean_img]
[Jean_img]
```

I want to build a CNN to treat the image and then concatenate the output of the CNN with the numpy array.
There is a repetition of images in my second input. It uses a lot of RAM and execute the same calculation on the CNN several times. So I would like to know if there is any way to optimize it?

The model is more complex than in the following code but you should have the idea with it.

```
image_input = K.Input(shape=(512, 512, 60,), name="img_input")
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(image_input)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2))(x)
cnn_output = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
    
numpy_input = K.Input(shape=(10,), name="numpy_input")
x = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([cnn_output, numpy_input], axis=1)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(x)

    
output= tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
    
model = K.Model(inputs=[image_input, numpy_input], outputs=output)
```

Plotting the model:

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
```

[Link to Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAY0X.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "For the second, repeating the image of a 'Patient' each time he appears is memory consuming"? It will be helpful if you could elaborate on your problem.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I edited the post. Tell me if it's understandable.

Comment: Notions of  "Each 'Patient' can have several rows," and "repeating the image of a 'Patient' each time he appears is memory consuming" are not clear, can you give more details.

Comment: @TouYou I updated the post. Tests are made on each Patient regularly. Each test will appear is a row in my array. The image is unique for each Patient. For each row of a Patient, I use this image. The repetition of this image uses too much of the RAM. And the image is calculated several times throught the CNN.

Comment: image_input = K.Input(shape=(512, 512, 60,) did you mean  shape=(512, 512, 60) with 60 channel?

Comment: You have used an Input layer so you don't have to specify  input_shape in the second layer x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(input_shape=(224,224,1,) And why the input shapes are different?

Comment: @TouYou Sorry, I didn't have time to answer earlier. The image has 60 channel because it's a 3D image. Each of the channel represents one slice in gray color. And it's a mistake of copy paste for the input shape on the Conv2D layer. It shouldn't have an input_shape. I think I have found the solution. I still need to optimize it more. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer: it is possible to implement the training from scratch. The solution is then to forward pass the CNN, then to contenate the CNN forward pass with tabular input and apply the forward pass of the second part of the NN. Finally, I just need to apply the back propagation. I put the link of the guide to write the training from scratch [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch#speeding-up_your_training_step_with_tffunction). And my code if it can be useful:

```
epochs = 1
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))
    j=0

    # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
    for [X1, X2], Y in generator:

        # Open a GradientTape to record the operations run
        # during the forward pass, which enables auto-differentiation.
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # Forward pass for CNN
            out_imgs = CNN(X2)
            # Replicate the forward pass in the same order than the numpy array
            patients = X1.loc[:, 'Patient'].unique()
            X_imgs = np.empty([X1.shape[0], out_imgs.shape[1]])
            for i in range(len(patients)):
                X_imgs[np.where(X1['Patient']==patients[i])] = out_imgs.numpy()[i]
            # Concatenate the forward pass with the numpy array
            inp_mlp = [tf.keras.layers.concatenate([0.1*X_imgs, np.asarray(X1[temp_SELECTED_COLUMNS])], axis=1)]
            # Forward pass of the second part of the layer
            for layer in model.layers[-3:]:
                inp_mlp.append(layer(inp_mlp[-1]))
            # Calculate loss
            loss = model.compiled_loss(tf.constant(Y), inp_mlp[-1], regularization_losses=model.losses)
```